# sed: Is there an option to substitute the Nth AND Mth occurrence of a match per line?

Tags: sed, string-substitution

I believe I am asking about pattern flags.

I am familiar with the global pattern flag 'g'

`sed 's/pattern/sub/g'`

And I know I can substitute the Nth occurrence of a match by using a number.

`sed 's/pattern/sub/2'`

But suppose I wanted to substitute the Nth AND Mth match on a line.

**Example:**
Remove the 3rd and 5th word of the following string

*Input:* "one two three four five six"

*Output:* "one two four six"

Comment: you can use `echo 'one two three four five six' | cut -d' ' -f1-2,4,6-` for given sample... (note your wording doesn't match sample)... with `sed` you can use multiple subs `sed 's/pattern/sub/2'; s/pattern/sub/3` but have to be careful that `3` in second sub is actually `4th` as first sub wiped out one `pattern`

Comment: I fixed my sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+\s*//5;s///3' file
```

This removes the fifth and then the third non-spaced followed by possible spaced groups of characters.

N.B. The removal is reversed i.e. 5 then 3 so that the previous removal does not affect the next.